# How to set auto incremented id to another column with using Peta Poco

Tags: c#, sql-server, petapoco

I use C#, SQL Server and PetaPoco which auto increments the `ID` by default. I just want to know that if it is possible to set this autoincremented id to another column.

I have 2 more columns needs to be set with the exact value of ID. Is it possible to do this inside the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement or doing some hook before or after `ExecuteNonQuery`? I don't want to create a view or a trigger if it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course - the `CREATE TABLE` allows you to define *which* column will be the auto-increment column, by adding the `IDENTITY` keyword to the column definition. This works for any integer-based column, or columns of type `DECIMAL(p, 0)` (with a `0` scale - no after-the-dot digits).

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    SomeOtherColumn BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ....
)
```

See the [MS docs on `CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the full and complete details

**UPDATE:** so you have 3 separate third-party applications, that all access this table, and all expect to find specific columns - one of which you can make the identity column. The two others could be **computed, persisted** "copies" of that identity column - something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    YourIdentityColumn BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ....
    SpecialColumnForApp2 AS YourIdentityColumn PERSISTED,
    SpecialColumnForApp3 AS YourIdentityColumn PERSISTED,
    ....
)
```

Comment: But only one identity column per table is allowed. I have 3 columns needs to be set with the same ID while new object created. In your example, I need 2 more IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL column.

Comment: @umtc: as you say - only **one** column can be decorated with the `IDENTITY` value. As of SQL Server 2012, you could possibly creates `SEQUENCES` for other columns, if you **really** need them (but ***why?!?!?!?!*** would you need **three** identity columns in a single table??)

Comment: I guess I couldn't explain well. I have integrated 3 projects and one of the projects has many dependencies to IDs. If I have time I would delete this project and start to code from scratch. So I don't need 3 identity columns I was just asking if there is a way to set those other 2 columns with identity column's value without writing update scripts or create a view or a trigger.

Comment: @umtc: if you want to update columns to a value - trigger is the most logical way to do it. But ***why*** do you need ***3*** columns with identical values?? Can't those apps just all access the **ONE** identity column???

Comment: That's the thing. I can't control those apps and already told the owners to do it. But for now I need a work around and I have used trigger already. I just thought if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @umtc: just thought of a possible way to handle this - see my updated response - use **computed, persisted** columns to "duplicate" the identity column to whatever columns those other applications require - nicely, declaratively, no view, no trigger, no other code needed

Comment: that's what I am exactly looking for. Thank you sir!